# raspian is using my old network setup from my old ISP

Tags: raspberry-pi

I switched ISPs today and decided to see how my pis were doing. All worked fine except for one. The stubborn one seems to refuse to update its network settings. Insisting it uses the old IP address. I've tried rebooting it, restarting the network service. I looked online and tried messing with resolv.conf. Nothing. I looked all over online for anything that relates to my problem and turned out with nothing. Before I format my SD card, I would like to see if this problem is fixable. What can I do? where can you delete your network settings on a pi. What makes this pi so special compared to my two other ones that adjust to their new network fine?

These pis are connected via Ethernet.

thank you in advance

PS. I ran netstat -ns and found that it pretty much still thinks that my old modem is still there. my old modem used DHCP settings that started with 192 while my new modem uses one that starts with 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. If this ever happens to you for some odd reason, be sure to gain root access and type either `ifdown eth#` or `ifup eth#` ("#" represents the number of your Ethernet device. usually 0). this will force the network service to recheck your network settings.

Comment: Something else may have happened, this is not normal behaviour.

Comment: Did you actually try to _reboot_ the Raspberry pi? This should have gone away with a reboot. Maybe whatever network script you restarted was not the one controlling this network connection, or the "[service] restart" action skipped some steps and so there was no change. As you're using DHCP, my guess is that the other machines had already renewed their DHCP leases, but this specific machine didn't.

Comment: That actually sounds very possible, I will try to renew the DCHP lease on my pi. But yes, I did reboot the pi. I disconnected the power source, reconnected it, ran 'sudo reboot.' Whole 9 yards.